# curve extremizing the functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Let $y \in C^([0,\pi])$ satisfying $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$ and $\int_0 ^\pi y^2(x)dx=1$ extremizes the functional

$J(y)=\int_0^\pi (y'^2(x))dx$ then

1. $y(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \sin x$
2. $y(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \sin x$
3. $y(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \cos x$
4. $y(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \cos x$

its answer is  (1)(2)

$y(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}$ and $y(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \cos x$ does not extremizes the functional as both does not satisfy the $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$.

$F(x,y,y')=(y'^2(x))$ applying Euler's equation

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}= C$

solving this i am not getting option 1 and 2 .

Please help, Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You have forgotten to consider the constraint $\int_0 ^\pi y^2(x)dx=1$. If the our problem is

$$\begin{align}
I(y) &= \int_{x_0}^{x_1}f(x,y,y^{'}) \\
y(x_0) &= y_0 \\
y(x_1) &= y_1 \\
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}g(x,y,y') &= C
\end{align}$$

then the function satisfying the Euler-Lagrange equation is

$$ \begin{align}
f+\lambda g &= h \\
\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial h}{\partial y^{'}}  &=0  
\end{align}$$

where $\lambda$ is an unknown constant which should be determined.

So in your example we have

$$h = y'^2 + \lambda y^2$$

Comment: yes, thanks i was really forget to use that condition.

Comment: @slowbutkeenlearner: You are welcome. :) You can accept the answer if you think it fits or Do you want me add more details?

Comment: I get the solution